# Ajax and jQuery working together

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am working with Ajax and jQuery. I have this code:

```
      <fieldset id="question-1">
    <p>
      <label>Question 1</label>
    </p>
    <p>Login to the server via POST /users/sign_in.</p>
    <p>Print out your user info</p>
    <p>Hint: (Data: {user: {email: "your_franklin_email", password: "franklin!"}})</p>
    <p>(Keep a reference to the token as you'll need it in the next steps.)</p>
    <p class="output"></p>
  </fieldset>
```

and my code to interact with this is:

```
var login = function(callback){
    $.ajax({
        url:baseURL + "/users/sign_in",
        type:"POST",
        data: "user[email]=nelson24%40email.franklin.edu&user[password]=franklin!",
        datatype:"json",
    }).success(function(arg1, arg2, jqXHR)){
        var result = "";
        $each(arg1, (function(key, value){
            if ("token" == key){
                token == value;
            } 
            result += key + ' ' + value;
        });
        $('#question-1 .output').html(result);
        callback (three);
    }
```

};

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is actually happening? Can you check the browser developer tools to see if data is returned? Are there any javascript errors?

Comment: do you actually __call__ the login function at any point?

Comment: You have a typo: `$each` should be `$.each`. Also the line `token == value;` should probably use `=` not `==`, and the variables `token` and `three` are not declared.

Comment: Can you give the console error, without it its difficult to tell what all is breaking, leaving the points nnnnnn described above